# Problem installing network printer [Solved]

Tags: networking, drivers, printing, hp

I am using **Ubuntu 16.04 LTS** in my lab and tried to install **HP LaserJet Pro 402dn** which is a network printer via an ethernet. I have tried using the suggested methods i.e., add printer > device url > installing driver and all...

The problem I am facing is whenever I try to print anything, the queue status shows **Processing - Not connected?**

I have CUPS already installed on my system and I have allowed the printer IP on the firewall as well. Can someone suggest me how to get rid of this?
[image]

Comment: Is it connected by ethernet to the router? Does it have it's own (reserved) IP address? What URI did you use? Is `hplip` installed? If so, your Ubuntu system should auto-detect the printer.

Comment: It is connected via ethernet and I have already installed hplip. The problem is now solved. I was not being able to ping that was shown in the printer LCD. I have changed that IP and now everything is working fine. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Awesome! Glad it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Answered by [OP](https://askubuntu.com/users/815496/nash-j) in [question](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1022568/2):

> I was not able to ping to the IP that the printer LCD was showing. I have changed the IP through the printer and reinstalled the printer on my computer. Things are working fine now.